# Latent Dirichlet Allocation in R, topicmodels using VEM algorithm or Gibbs Sampling mixing tm and topicmodels library or WarpLDA from text2vec?

Tags: text-mining, algorithms, topic-model, lda

If I am trying to classify 230k text abstracts, which option would be better and more precise when aplying LDA?

Comment: You should try all the options and analyze/evaluate the results imho

Comment: Happen to know how to evaluate when different algorithms are being used? Is it ok if I use perplexity on both?

Comment: technical measures like perplexity are not suitable for a proper evaluation because they are not based on on the semantics of the task. If a proper evaluation is not possible they might give a partial indication though. See e.g. https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/60506/64377